# Crawl again from the exceptional page using Python

Tags: python, for-loop, try-catch, except

I use a for loop to crawl web pages. However, i encounter ip request limit error when i am crawling some pages. I have tried to make python sleep some seconds when i has crawled every 20 pages, however, the error holds. I can start to crawl again after python sleeps 60 secs.

The problem is each time, when there is an exception, i will lose a page of information. It seems that python jumps over the exceptional page using the try-except method.

I am wondering the best way is to restart to crawl again from the page which has encountered the exception.

My question is how to restart to crawl from the exceptional page.

```
pageNum = 0

for page in range(1, 200):
    pageNum += 1
    if(pageNum % 20 ==0):  # every 20 pages sleep 180 secs
        print 'sleeep 180 secs'
        time.sleep(180)  # to oppress the ip request limit
    try:
        for object in api.repost_timeline(id=id, count=200, page=page): 
            mid = object.__getattribute__("id")
            # my code here to store data
    except:
        print "Ip request limit", page
        sleep.time(60)
```

Comment: So what is your question? Your code seems to work (or at least it is in the right direction).

Comment: thank you for your reminding. The problem is each time, when there is an exception, i will lose a page of information. It seems that python jumps over the exceptional page using the try-except method.

I am wondering the best way is to restart to crawl again from the page which has encountered the exception.

My question is how to restart to crawl from the exceptional page.

Comment: shouldn't you just put the try and except inside the for object loop?

Comment: `object.__getattribute__("id")` is a very weird way to write `object.id`

Comment: @Junuxx: I think i had done as you say. However, there will be some exceptional pages, i want to crawl them again, rather than let them go by just trying once.

Comment: @JochenRitzel: yes. however, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `stack` of pages. `pop` a page, if it fails then append again.

```
from collections import deque

page_stack = deque()
for page in range(199, 0, -1):
    page_stack.append(page)

while len(page_stack):
    page = page_stack.pop()

    try:
        ## Do something
    except IPLimitException, e:
        page_stack.append(page)
```

The code can run into infinite loop. Based on your need you can keep a threshold of trials that you can make. Keep a counter and do not append the page back to stack if that threshold is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the code as closest as possible to yours, you could just do something like:

```
pageNum = 0

for page in range(1, 200):
    pageNum += 1
    if(pageNum % 20 ==0):  # every 20 pages sleep 180 secs
        print 'sleeep 180 secs'
        time.sleep(180)  # to oppress the ip request limit
    succeeded = False
    while not succeeded:
        try:
            for object in api.repost_timeline(id=id, count=200, page=page): 
                mid = object.__getattribute__("id")
                # my code here to store data
            succeeded = True
        except:
            print "Ip request limit", page
            sleep.time(60)
```

Of course you may want to include some sort of limit instead of risking to enter an endless loop. Btw, you can also get rid of pageNum (just use page).